# "Cooking" is to "culinary" as "dining" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

The art of cooking is called culinary art. Is there a comparable term for the art of eating or dining?

Is there a more sophisticated term?

Comment: I'd say gourmetism, but I just made that one up...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [gastronomy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gastronomy)

> the art or science of good eating

Comment: This is the only term suggested that I would expect to hear in day-to-day conversation.

Comment: @Ina Really?  I use epicurean far more often than gastronom<y|ic>.

Comment: @John Perhaps your friends are just a little more epicurean than mine ;)

Comment: @Ina I doubt it.  They're not even close to as good as I am.

Comment: I believe epicurean should refer to *any* form of "good living"/"pleasures", not simply "good eating and drinking". At least, this is the meaning in Italian and it's also more related to epicurean philosophy then the simple gastronomical aspect.

Comment: @Bakuriu Unfortunately, Italian is not English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You are right. Probably in people in England didn't study much philosophy when they coined the word, otherwise it *would* have the same meaning. However people that know Epicurus may want to hint to a broader meaning using that term; *even in English*.

Comment: I use the word gastronomic at the end of every meal: 'Gastronomic satiety admonishes me that I have arrived at a state of deglutition consistent with dietetic integrity.'

Answer (score 16):

You might consider **epicurean**:

> *adjective*
>   **2** relating to or suitable for an epicure
>
> **epicure** *noun*
>   a person who takes particular pleasure in fine food and drink
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/epicure)

**Gastronomic** might fit, although that does include the whole process including cooking:

> **gastronomy**  *noun*
>   [*mass noun*]
>       the practice or art of choosing, cooking, and eating good food.
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gastronomy)

Comment: Usage Note: A gourmet is a person with discriminating taste in food and wine, as is a gourmand. Because gourmand can also mean "one who enjoys food in great quantities" or even "a gluttonous eater," care should be taken to make clear its intended sense. An **epicure** is much the same as a gourmet, but the word may sometimes carry overtones of excessive refinement. This use of epicure is a misrepresentation of Epicurean philosophy, which, while it professed that pleasure was the highest good, was hardly given to excessive concern with food and drink.(The American Heritage Dictionary of the EL)

Answer (score 8):

I think that is called

[Aristology](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aristology)

> **Ar`is`tol´o`gy** 
> n.  1.  The science of dining.

[Aristology Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristology)

> Aristology is the art or science of cooking and dining. It encompasses
>   the preparation, combination, and presentation of dishes and the
>   manner in which these dishes are integrated into a meal.

Answer (score 5):

Another word specific to eating manners is ***gastrosophy*** or the science of good eating.

A [*gastrosoph*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gastrosophy) is comparable to *gastronome*.

Comment: Gastrosophe sounds to me like what happens when you eat so much you explode (as in The Meaning of Life.)

Comment: And how does gastronome sound to you.

Answer (score 4):

*Cooking* and *kitchen* is to *culinary* (Latin *culina* "kitchen") as *dining* and *feast/banquet* is to *epulary* (Latin *epulum* "feast").

So where one might use *culinary arts* for the art of cooking, I suppose one might use *epulary arts* for the art of dining and preparing a feast.

**Dictionary reference:**

- [epulary - Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/epulary)

Comment: This specifically refers to feast, which is very different from dining.

Comment: @user49727 In what world are "feasting" and "dining" *very* different. There's definitely a subtle difference, but I wouldn't say *very* different.

Comment: When it comes to manners and science feasting is a very specific form of dining and could be misleading if used in the generic sense that culinary is. This is nevertheless a good word to know.

Comment: @user49727 True, but it is *a* valid sophisticated form of dining, and thus an appropriate answer--if only in certain cases.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion: *Gustatory*.

Comment: I think this is good, but it might correspond more literally to 'tasting' rather than 'dining'.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of words "the art of eating or dining" puts me in mind of [table etiquette (or manners)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_manners):

> Table manners are the rules of etiquette used while eating, which may also include the appropriate use of utensils.

I'm not certain if that's what you mean or not. I can't form a clear analogy between cooking and eating, because they are fundamentally different to me. Cooking is *creating* while dining is *consuming*. The other answers focus on the art of good eating, which is much more closely related to the creation, selection or preparation of foods in addition to their actual consumption. Along that line of reasoning, you might as well say:

> Cooking is to culinary as dining is to [diet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diet_%28nutrition%29).

Diet can encompass selection of meals, types of foods, balance of proportions, methods of preparation as well as when and how to actually consume meals. It doesn't have an intrinsic connotation of good or bad, fine or gross. Just as you can have good cooking and bad cooking, you have good diets and bad diets.

On the other hand is my fork. I mean, on the other hand, you have etiquette. I consider table manners and etiquette to be strictly focused on the art of actually consuming the food, i.e. dining.

Answer (score 0):

[Gourmet (adj)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/gourmet_1) can be used. It's serving of food/meals that are of very high quality.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a good analogy like that because cooking and dining are opposite sides of the culinary coin.  Cooking prepares the food, dining consumes it.

How about cooking:dining :: printing:reading?  Although reading isn't a destructive consumption like dining is.

Answer (score 0):

Like the adjective culinary, which pertains to matters of food preparation, there is an adjective which pertains to eating, namely *alimentary*.  This does not pertain to dining specifically, which is a formalization of eating. It pertains more to the overall nutritional aspect of food.

I suspect you want to use this adjective in sentences like "A(n) __ experience" (where __ could be replaced by *dining*, but should be occupied by some adjective).  The word alimentary does seem to be elastic enough to stretch so that "a great alimentary experience" is a passable way to say "great dining experience". This is one of those rarely used words that you can somewhat abuse, because most people haven't looked it up in a dictionary and will assume that you have, yet many will remember that it has something to do with eating.